# Are there uses of the word eidetic not involving the word "memory"?

Tags: collocation

Title says it all. Are there ways to use the word eidetic that don't follow it immediately with the word memory? Seems like a waste of word with wonderfully unusual spelling.

Comment: The spelling is no mystery.  It is derived from the Greek word 'eidos'.  Plato used this as the word for the true being  of the abstract entities of which reality, he thought, is composed.  The adjective from 'eidos' is 'eidētikos'.  Ironically, 'eidos' is from the past tense 'eidon', whose infinitive is 'idein' = 'to see'.  Also formed from this word is the word 'idea':  not, you will notice 'eidea', just as the word derived from Greek 'eironeia' is not 'eirony'.

Comment: I didn't say the spelling was a mystery. I said it was wonderfully unusual in comparison to most English words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eidetic) entry has

> **eidetic**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Relating to or denoting mental images having unusual vividness and detail, as if actually visible.

with the example

> Although in traditional practices of visualization, eidetic images of a divinity or his paradisal dwelling were constructed in the mind, these visions were not visible to the eyes.

This example isn't about memory, but invocation techniques.

Comment: This is indeed the sense that the word is most likely to have in its present-day usage (in so far as it is used at all), but among those who are familiar with Greek philosophy it may also occasionally be used as the English rendering of 'eidētikos', which is, as can be seen in Tuffy's comment,  the adjective formed from 'eidos' (a word rich in philosophical associations that are not fully captured by any of its standard translations into modern languages).